# Partly change the background color of UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIView` with some labels and a background color for the `UITableViewCell`. When it is displayed I want the background color to be split into two (30% red, 70% grey). I've tried to hide in using sublayers, but, that gets tricky because my cell is resized randomly when tapped, therefore I have to manually update `CGRect` of my sublayer. Any ideas on how can I do that another way?

Here's what I've tried. It does the thing, but managing the resize event is hard. (Gradient is just to be it colorful)

```
extension UIView{
    func addGradientLayer(points: Float){

        let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer! = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.6, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        let layer1 = CALayer()
        let x = CGFloat(points/100) * layer.bounds.width
        let frameOn = CGRect(x: x, y: 0.0, width: bounds.width - x, height: bounds.height)
        layer1.cornerRadius = 20
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 20
        layer1.frame = frameOn
        layer1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.insertSublayer(layer1, at: 0)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: Why not add 2 empty `UIView` as the background? I would avoid working with layers if auto layout can do the job.

Comment: @RickyMo Yeah, I've thought of this, but I wonder if there's way to do it with one view

Comment: I think best to apply UITableViewCell ContentView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello I hope it will help you,

```
//Top to Bottom Gradient
extension UIView {
    func setGradientBackground() {
        let colorTop =  UIColor.red.cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint =  CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint =  CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.7)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}

//Left to Right Gradient
extension UIView {
    func setGradientBackground() {
        let colorLeft =  UIColor.red.cgColor
        let colorRight = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorLeft, colorRight]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint =  CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint =  CGPoint(x: 0.3, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This kind of idea kinda solves the problem, but it requires code for managing resize event for the backgroundLayer

Comment: @NikitaKrasnov can you please try this DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.viewGradient.setGradientBackground()
        }